# Why does docker-compose build a new image on `docker-compose up`?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up`, why does a new image get created? How can I tell docker-compose to run with the image I just created? What am I doing wrong here?

When I run the command `docker build . -t prod_srdc_web` from a clean system, using `docker system prune -a`, everything is built fine. When I run `docker image ls` after building the image I see the following:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
prod_srdc_web       latest              923538608c06        5 seconds ago        1.1GB
<none>              <none>              04b24dbf7c93        About a minute ago   4.23MB
python              3.7                 42d620af35be        9 days ago           918MB
alpine              3.7                 6d1ef012b567        4 months ago         4.21MB
```

After I run `docker-compose up` everything gets built again and the container launches. Now `docker image ps` shows an identical image with a new name, `srdc_django_web`:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
srdc_django_web     latest              7e75a841e0fd        About a minute ago   1.1GB
prod_srdc_web       latest              923538608c06        2 minutes ago        1.1GB
<none>              <none>              04b24dbf7c93        4 minutes ago        4.23MB
python              3.7                 42d620af35be        9 days ago           918MB
alpine              3.7                 6d1ef012b567        4 months ago         4.21MB
```

Why does `docker-compose up` build a new image? Ideally I'd like to use the image I just built and tagged, `prod_srdc_web`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache build-base gcc python=3.7 python3-dev postgresql-dev bash git

ENV LIBRARY_PATH=lib:/usr/lib

FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /code && mkdir -p /var/www/website.com/static/
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install gunicorn

# Copy project
COPY . /code

# Copy entrypoint.prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh /

EXPOSE 4500

# Run entrypoint.prod.sh
RUN [ "chmod", "+x", "./entrypoint.prod.sh" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.prod.sh" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  django_web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/srdc
    ports:
      - "4500:4500"
    container_name: srdc_c_django_web
```

**entrypoint.prod.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
gunicorn srdc.wsgi:application -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:4500
```

It looks like the repository name `srdc_django_web` is created by concatenating the directory name (`srdc`) with the service name in the docker-compose.yml file (`django_web`). If I eventually add Nginx I want to use docker-compose up to run the entire container `prod_srdc_web`, not have it build each service fresh.

FYI my versions are:

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compose file does not specify an image name. Therefore, even if you build the image in advance manually, docker-compose does not have any mapping from the build you want to run and the image you've already created. To give an image name, specify:

```
version: '3'

services:
  django_web:
    build: .
    image: prod_srdc_web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/srdc
    ports:
      - "4500:4500"
    container_name: srdc_c_django_web
```

Docker will use the image cache to avoid recreating the same image layers that it already has. However, since you have the following:

```
COPY . /code
```

Any file in the build context (the current directory, assuming you do not ignore files with a `.dockerignore`) that changes will result in a new image being created. That can include file ownership and permissions, and files like the docker-compose.yml if they are in this directory are also included.

Comment: We have created a volume. Why would we us write `COPY . /code` again?

Comment: @AliReza adding the code to the image makes it usable in production or other areas where you only pull the image and not the source code. Mounting the volume is a useful development practice to avoid rebuilding the image for every change.

Comment: Thanks @BMitvh. I'm a bit confuse with in spite we have a volume, we copy all stuff (in the Dockerfile) again. Imagine you have a python project. You store all needed packages in a `requirements,txt` file. Whenever you install a new package, you modify the file so that you have the updated file in your running container. (There is no package installed in the container)

Now, you need to rebuild your image. I mean yeah you need to copy the project at first, but after that there is a volume that takes these steps away,